# operator does not exist: geometry <#> geometry

Tags: postgis-2.0

I'm running PostGIS 2.0 for PostGreSQL 9.2, and I have a customer who wants to know how close a provided geometry is to the nearest feature in a table. So I'm playing around with the "<->" and "<#>" operators.  My problem?  The "<#>" operator isn't recognized.

This works:

```
SELECT gid, 
    the_geom <-> ST_GeomFromEWKT('<my geometry>')
    FROM "<my table>"
    ;
```

This does not:

```
SELECT gid, 
    the_geom <#> ST_GeomFromEWKT('<my geometry>')
    FROM "<my table>"
    ;
```

I get an error:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: geometry <#> geometry
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: With psql, do you see it with `\do <#>`? And/or with pgAdmin, do you see it in the list of operators?

Comment: It shows up, in psql, with "\do <#>" - left arb of abstime, right arg of abstime, result type of tinterval. Which doesn't seem to fit the description I see in the docs. "\do <->" shows a number of operators, taking box and box, circle and circle, circle and polygon, etc.

Comment: There is a problem with your installation, since the operator for `geometry` is not there. How did you install PostGIS to this database? Did you use the `EXTENSION`, etc.?

Comment: also `box`, `circle`, `polygon` are *not* PostGIS types.

Comment: I was mistaken, earlier.  My local machine is Windows7, running PostGIS 2.0 for PostgreSQL 9.2 - and it's from that install from which come the clients I'm using (psql and PgAdmin). But the database I'm connecting to is running on an Ubuntu system, onto which the postgresql-8.4-postgis package has been installed.  It seems to be running PostgreSQL 8.4.8.